# Laravel 8: How To Use Intervention Image Library Properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, intervention

I want to use [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io) library for my Laravel project, so I just installed it via Composer and added this line of code to `config/app.php`:

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
```

And also this line was added to `aliases` part:

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
```

Now at my Controller I coded this:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    protected function uploadImages($file)
    {
        $year = Carbon::now()->year;
        $imagePath = "/upload/images/{$year}/";
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file = $file->move(public_path($imagePath), $filename);
        $sizes = ["300","600","900"];
        Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(300,null,function($constraint){
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save(public_path($imagePath . "300_" . $filename));
    }
}
```

But as soon as I fill my form to check if it's work or not, this error message pops up:

> **Error**
> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Image' not found

Which means this line:

```
Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(300,null,function($constraint){
```

So why it returns this error while I've included it already in my project ?!

If you know, please let me know... I would really appreciate that.

Thanks

Comment: add `use Image;` on the top

Comment: @sta Thanks, so concise and so useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `config/app.php` you need to add :

```
$provides => [
    Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
],
```

And,

```
$aliases => [

    'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
]
```

Now you can call `use Image;` on the top on your controller :

```
use Image;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That has two versions. If v3 bit different than v2. Someone needs to know the configuration process and follow the steps via that link. It has an example.
https://neaptech.com/laravel-images-intervention/